# target particular form on a page w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the values of the form text fields, if any entered, before the form is submitted.

Let's say I have form **A** and user inputs some values, but then clicks some other link on a page and opens a dialog which contains form **B**. If the user submits form **B** the results  will post on the page and will refresh it, which is what I want, but it will loose all the values from the fields of form **A**.

What I need is to run run through a loop through form fields of form A when form **B** is submitted and get the "non-empty" fields from form **A**, in a form of HTML and insert that HTML into the refreshed page along with the results posted from form **B**.

Said that, what I need now is to be able to get HTML with values entered into one VAR when a **myLink** is clicked.

```
$('#myForm:input').each(function(){

     var fieldWithValue = "";

     if($(this).val() != "") {
         $this = $(this);
         fieldWithValue += $this.parent().html();    
     }
     $("#vals").html(fieldWithValue);
})


<form id="myForm">

    foreach ($arrays as $listValue) {
        <div>
           <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="field[]">
        </div>
    }

    <div id="vals"></div>

</form>

<a href="#" id="myLink">link</a>
```

I think this can be done using .html()...

Answer (score 1):

Your question says "write it all into a variable and post back on a page after it is refreshed." Taken literally that sounds odd because it's not like a JS variable persists after you refresh the page, if you're really using a full page refresh.

So if that is the approach you're really taking, this might be where you want to start: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ Normally that's what you'd use to grab all fields' values out of a form to send to a server (on an ajax call, for instance).

So, what you might do is:

- Serialize your target form and save the serialized string to a cookie, with the cookie named after id of the form values it's storing
- On page load, look for elements that match your cookie names and fill in the values from the cookie values. You could do this on the server or in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

From your example code, you'd be much better off using something like [serialize(](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)).

Check the output of the following after submitting your current form and see if it is what you're after.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
});
```

Comment: I suggest updating your question to better define your needs.